# Serenity cucumber show each step on console

Tags: java, logging, cucumber, serenity-bdd

I add log4j.properties to my project but serenity does not want to write all steps he performed on console. Could you please help me?

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=Test.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
#log4j.appender.file.Append=false
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Here is my log4j config. but I can not see any of steps from my .feature file showed up on console or Test.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Serenity BDD properties [here](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_serenity_system_properties_and_configuration).

There are `serenity.verbose.steps` and `serenity.logging` properties which you might find useful.